# I have made a scrollable box layout but it does not scroll

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating a scrollable box layout in Kivy but it is not scrolling even after putting the box layout inside ScrollView

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from  kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
kv = '''
ScrollView:
##    size=(root.width, root.height)
    do_scroll_y: True
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'
        Label:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            size: (100,100)
            text: 'my text'

class theApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
if name == 'main':
    theApp().run()
```

Expected result is a scrollable box layout. but actual result is non scrollable. After searching out about ScrollView I found that I just need to put the layout inside it and it works easily but it does not in this case. Do let me know whats my mistake in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give our BoxLayout widget a height constraint and set the size_hint_y property of our BoxLayout widget to None.

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jerome, now I know why I was not getting the result.